# Lighttpd and Redmine on a subdomain give 500 error

Tags: sockets, redmine, lighttpd

Ok, I got my CentOS6 VPS and Lighttpd work like a charm. I installed Redmine, got it working on Webrick. When I killed Webrick and tried to host Redmine on Lighttpd using fastcgi the only message I got was a 500. My PHP applications work fine.

Every time I try to access my redmine I get these two messages on my log files:

> (mod_fastcgi.c.2543) unexpected end-of-file (perhaps the fastcgi process died): pid: 8490 socket: unix:/tmp/redmine.socket-0
>
> (mod_fastcgi.c.3329) response not received, request sent: 597 on socket: unix:/tmp/redmine.socket-0 for /dispatch.fcgi?, closing connection

/tmp/ is writable, lighttpd user owns all redmine files and my lighttpd.conf file is as follows:

```
 $HTTP["host"] =~ "redmine.domain.com" {
        server.document-root = "/path/to/redmine/public"
        server.errorlog = "/path/to/redmine/log/lighttpd.log"
                accesslog.filename = "/path/to/redmine/log/access.log"
        magnet.attract-physical-path-to = ( "/path/to/redmine/tmp/cleanurl.lua" )
        fastcgi.server    = ( "dispatch.fcgi" =>
                ((
                        "socket" => "/tmp/lighttpd/redmine.socket",
                        "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/ruby /path/to/redmine/public/dispatch.fcgi",
                        "max-procs" => 1,
                        "idle-timeout" => 20,
                        "kill-signal" => 9,
                        "bin-environment" => (
                               "RAILS_ENV" => "production",
                                "TARGET" => "/path/to/redmine/public/dispatch.fcgi"
                        )
                ))
        )
}
```

Lighttpd restart fine, no errors there.

Of course, /path/to/redmine points to my actual redmine folder.

Software versions:

> CentOS 6 x64
>   Lighttpd 1.4.31
>   Ruby 1.8.7
>   Rails 3.2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working afterall. I just needed to add two requires to my dispatch.fcgi file, like below:

> require 'rubygems'
>   require 'fcgi'

Tip: They **have** to go to the top of the file, right before the other requires there.

/topic closed.

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted, this is the way to tell other people that your problem is solved (or closed as you want)

Comment: I know, it just tells me that I will have to wait about 10 minutes more.